# Rx (JS) selectively unsubscribe observables in a flatMap

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

Is there a way to cancel/remove individual observables in a `flatMap` or `concatMap` operation before they complete?

I currently have an observable of UI actions that trigger API requests, and I use `flatMap` for this:

```js
actionsFromUI.flatMap(a => http.request("blah?id=" + a.id))
```

This is then subscribed to render results. A really nice property of this is that if I unsubscribe, all in-progress API requests are automatically cancelled. I don't want to break that.

Now I want to support UI actions that can cancel a *particular* in-progress request. A UI action can trigger an API request for a particular ID, and then a subsequent UI action can then cancel the API request for that ID.

I hope this dummy code illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```js
let actions = [
    { action: "start", id: 1 },
    { action: "start", id: 2 },
    { action: "start", id: 3 },
    { action: "cancel", id: 1 },
    { action: "start", id: 4 },
    { action: "cancel", id: 3 },
    { action: "start", id: 1 }
];

Observable.from(actions)
    .flatMap(a => {
        if (a.action === "start") {
            return http.request("blah?id=" + a.id);
        } else if (a.action === "cancel") {
            // ???
        }
    })
    .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Does RxJS have the `.Switch()` operator? If so, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It does, but my understanding is that will cancel the previous API request each time a new one comes in. I want to have multiple in-progress requests, and then cancel a particular one. I realised my example code might be misleading... I have updated it.

Comment: There's no problem using `.Switch()` so long as you first `.GroupBy` the `id`. You can then have multiple queries running in parallel so long as they have different ids. I posted a solution using this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is way to do that.

You can use `takeUntil` operator for that.

It would be some think like this:

```
// actions - observable of user actions, each action has id field
// cancelActions - observable of action cancelations each has id of action to cancel
// doRequest - function that starts request and returns observable

const results = actions.flatMap(
  action => doRequest(action)
    .takeUntil(
      cancelActions.filter(cancel => cancel.id === action.id)
    )
);
```

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takeuntil.md

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this.

Start with an observable of the raw data:

```js
let actions = Observable.from([
    { action: "start", id: 1 },
    { action: "start", id: 2 },
    { action: "start", id: 3 },
    { action: "cancel", id: 1 },
    { action: "start", id: 4 },
    { action: "cancel", id: 3 },
    { action: "start", id: 1 }
]);
```

I then created two functions to simulate the processing and cancelling of the data:

```js
let start = n =>
    Observable
        .of(`Finished ${n}`)
        .delay(1000);

let cancel = n =>
    Observable
        .of(`Cancelled ${n}`);
```

I made `start` take 1 second to process and `cancel` return immediately.

Then I ran this query:

```js
let query =
    actions
        .groupBy(x => x.id)
        .map(gx =>
            gx
                .map(x => x.action === "start"
                    ? start(x.id)
                    : cancel(x.id))
                .switch())
        .mergeAll();
```

That gave me this result:

```
Cancelled 1 
Cancelled 3 
Finished 2 
Finished 4 
Finished 1
```

I think that behaves the way you want it.

<strike>I'd appreciate if someone could translate to JS for me.</strike>

Comment: I translated this to RxJS 5. For my use case, I replaced your `start` with the API call, and your `cancel` with `Observable.empty()`, and yes the switch aborts the API call when the cancel comes through. Thanks for posting a different approach.